# Using Devise, I don't see notices like "you've signed in" when i log into my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm building a basic app with Rails 3.2 and Devise 2.0. I've create a User devise model and a Projects model. In my routes.rb files I have

```
root :to => 'projects#index'
```

I can sign up and sign in at Get users/sign_up and Get users/sign_in, respectively, but when it redirects to projects#index, I don't see a notice at the top that says "You've signed in successfully. Which file do I need to check to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add flash messages showing to the file `/projects/index.html.erb`
for example this way:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks Alony, that worked. Isn't there supposed to be something like this line by default when I create a scaffold?

Comment: As I remember, it used to appear in the layout, but I'm very much not sure